# Why is inherited value printed out twice?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am practicing inheritance and I have a base class called `Person`. The `Person` has a variable called `age` and in the `Person` class constructor, I set `age` to `5` and print age to the screen. I have another class called `ballPerson` that inherits `age` from `Person` and sets `age` equal to `6`. when I create an object for my `Person` class and my `ballPerson` class, the value `5` (the value for `age` in the `Person` class) is printed out twice. why?

person.h

```
class Person
{
public:
    Person();
    int age;
    ~Person();
};
```

Person.cpp

```
Person::Person() : age(5)
{
    std::cout << age;
}
```

ballPerson.h

```
class ballPerson : public Person
{
public:
    ballPerson();
    ~ballPerson();
};
```

ballPerson.cpp

```
ballPerson::ballPerson()
{
    age = 6;
    std::cout << age;
}
```

main.cpp

```
int main()
{
    Person p;
    ballPerson bp;


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This prints `5`:

```
Person p;
```

And this prints `56`:

```
ballPerson bp;
```

Because `Person` (base class) constructor is called from `ballPerson` constructor.

Comment: I never  created an instance of person in my ball person class so why did it call the person constructor?

Comment: @RoundSquare because it's the base class, and it must be initialized first

Comment: Thanks. I think I get it now

Answer (score 0):

As Anton told, the child class calls its parents constructor when you instantiate the object. But, why is that?

Well, it's done by definition (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/derived_class), and if we take a look in the memory we can see it by ourselves.

```
ballPerson::ballPerson (this=0x7fffffffe400)
(gdb) p this
$14 = (ballPerson * const) 0x7fffffffe400
(gdb) p *this
$15 = {<Person> = {age = 4197216}, <No data fields>}
```

Look above, we are inside the ballPerson constructor, `this` points to `0x7fffffffe400`. Consulting `this`, we see it 'has' a `Person` object with a field `age` (uninitialized so far) within.

After the `ballPerson` constructor is initialized, just ready to be executed, the compiler calls `Person` constructor.

```
0x400af0 <ballPerson::ballPerson()+24>  callq  0x400a96 <Person::Person()>
```

And we can see:

```
Person::Person (this=0x7fffffffe400)
(gdb) p this
$6 = (Person * const) 0x7fffffffe400
(gdb) p *this
$7 = {age = 4197216}
```

it's the `Person` constructor and it's using the same `this` pointer, pointing to the same `0x7fffffffe400`.  After this, the code in `ballPerson` constructor is run.

In other words, imagine it's a hybrid between C and C++, the code would be:

```
ballPerson::ballPerson(ballPerson *this)
{
   Person(this);
   this->age = 6;
   std::cout << this->age;
}
```